# How windows functions "CreateWaitableTimer" and "SetWaitableTimer" can be implemented on Linux? Is there any equivalent replacement for them on Linux?

Tags: linux, rad-studio

The purpose of this query is I am porting windows calls to Linux.
Below is the piece of code from my application on how the windows API's are used :
CreateWaitableTimer() and SetWaitableTimer()

```
procedure WorkerExecute;
var
  Timer : THandle;
  WaitArray : array[0..1] of THandle;
  nextSchedule : integer;
  timeToSchedule : Int64;
begin
  try
    TlsSetValue(WorkerThreadTls, Pointer(self));
    Timer := CreateWaitableTimer(nil, true, nil);
    WaitArray[0] := Timer;
    WaitArray[1] := DispatchTrigger;
    nextSchedule := 0;
    while not Terminated do begin
      if nextSchedule > 0 then begin
        timeToSchedule := -10000 * nextSchedule; 
        SetWaitableTimer(Timer, timeToSchedule, 0, nil, nil, false);
        AtomicIncrement(SleepingWorkers);  
        if MsgWait then
          MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(2, WaitArray, false, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT)
        else
          WaitForMultipleObjects(2, @WaitArray, false, INFINITE);
           AtomicDecrement(SleepingWorkers)       
      end;
      nextSchedule := 100; // default: sleep 100 ms
      if SlaveWorker <> nil then begin
        // extra work for MainWorker
        if Sim.State = isStartInitialize then begin
          try
            Sim.InitializeLayers
          finally
            Sim.State := isInitialized
          end
        end;
        if Sim.State = isStartShutdownLayers then begin
          Sim.State := isShuttingDownLayers;
          Sim.ShutdownLayers
        end
      end;
      Sim.DispatchEvents(nextSchedule)
    end;
    CloseHandle(Timer);
    TlsSetValue(WorkerThreadTls, nil)
  except
    HandleException(self)
  end
end;
```

Comment: When porting code that uses the Windows API to Linux you will probably find more difficulties than the two named functions. What do you want to achieve with "porting windows calls to Linux"? Do you want to migrate the software from Windows to Linux? Do you want to get a portable software that will run on both systems? Please [edit] your question to answer. Maybe you can use Wine to run your Windows program on Linux.

Comment: You probably need to completely rewrite this part of your code as you will also have trouble porting `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` and `WaitForMultipleObjects`.

Comment: @Bodo  I want to migrate my complete windows application on native Linux . The application is a kind of simulator for performance test. Wine is already there but that has some drawbacks so now want to port the application on native Linux

Comment: Hi @fpmurphy yes there are lot many other functions which needs to be replaced . But for other functions i have some replication like you mentioned MsgWaitForMultipleObjects and WaitForMultipleObjects. But somehow I could not found out anything related to CreateWaitableTimer() and SetWaitableTimer()

Comment: @Anna **Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification, don't use comments for this purpose.** It might help to show how you plan replace the other functions. I suggest to add an explanation of the purpose of your procedure `WorkerExecute`. Instead of trying to replace individual Windows-specific function calls. There might be a more general portable alternative.